# Accessing classes in the same C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my C++ project, one of the `.cpp` files has a class declared. Now I want to instantiate this class in another `.cpp` file in the same project, but I get this error message:

```
error C2248: 'Processor' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Processor'
    c:\Test\wrapper.cpp : see declaration of 'Processor'
```

We can't redefine the class using a different access specifier, it gets the default `private` access specifier.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Do note that on MSVC++ compilers the `/CLR` option is off by default. The `[c++]` tag here refers to standard C++ (non `/CLR`). You don't have to qualify everything as non-`/CLR` or `unmanaged`.

Comment: Also, can you show us the code in question? Like what's in `wrapper.cpp` and the file where you declared the `Processor` class?

Comment: You are doing `#include "first.cpp"` in the second `.cpp` file?

Comment: @Naveen - yes I have included .CPP there.Is t not allwed? How should I change it?

Comment: If it is `private`, you should either have a `getter` for it and if you don't, you are not supposed to touch that variable. A `private` variable is made private for a reason and you insisting on accessing it directly shows a bug in your program's logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (in a clean way at least), and you shouldn't.

Making fields `private` (even by default) is the programmer's way of telling you *you're not supposed to instantiate this class*.

Also, if a class is defined inside a `cpp` file, it's only visible in that translation unit. You don't include `cpp` files. If you must, move the definition inside a header and include that, but not the `cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include the cpp file directly in your cpp file, it might cause all sort of problems. The class is inside a cpp file means that you are not supposed to use it from any other cpp file, if you really need that class then you need to move that class to an appropriate header and include the header file. But before doing that, first check whether any alternate ways to do what you are trying to do without exposing the new class.

Comment: I have now moved class declaration in header.But still I getting error as mentioned above. I don't have any other way available hence using I had to create class in non /cli project and use it. Can you please suggest any available good way?